# Listar custom post type de várias taxonomias

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomia, custom-post-types

Usei esse código:

```
<ul>
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'integrante',
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order'   => 'asc',
        'lang' => 'pt',
        'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'integrante_category',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'equipe_fundador','equipe_financas' )

            ),
        ),
    );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
?>

<li>
  <h3 class="nome"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
</li>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query();?>
</ul>
```

Ele retorna todos os post das duas taxonomias que coloquei. Porém, preciso que ele inclua uma divisão (*título*) entre uma taxonomia e outra, assim teria a marca de onde começa o loop de cada um.

Comment: pq não fazer dois loops distintos?

Comment: Eu acabei fazendo isso. Mas a minha dúvida era se tinha uma outra maneira. pq no caso, eu tenho 10 categorias, então fiz 10 loops.

Comment: você pode tentar ordenar de alguma maneira os resultados da WP_Query... uma flag dentro do loop talvez resolva, a questão é a ordenação. Eu vou dar uma pensada aqui

Answer (score 1):

Faça um loop de categorias onde você insere o cabeçalho da categoria, dentro desse loop você conseguirá os ids de todas as categorias, use isso para fazer mais um loop de posts, criando assim um par de loops aninhados, evitando ter que usar 10 loops distintos.

Vou codar algo aqui pra você